# arrenge checkbox with img side by side

Tags: checkbox, image

My checkboxes are presented by img.
I try to put them side by side but no sucsees.

I want this one: http://tinyurl.com/8g8ev2m (I did it by using Gravity Form, but unfortunly it doesnt meet my needs)

to look like this one: http://tinyurl.com/8m7g295

my code for the second one attached.

Thanks for your help.

```
.DesignCheckBox label {
               background-repeat: no-repeat;
               border: 2px solid #DDD;
                       height: 150px!important;
                       font-size: 150%;
                       -moz-border-radius: 20px;
                       -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px; 
            -khtml-border-radius: 20px; 
                       background-image: url(http://doarna.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/XCellcom.gif);
                       }

<?php
global $wpdb;
 $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_organization where type='תקשורת'";
 $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

       foreach ($results as $result) {
                   $MEATZBEN= $result->NAME;
                   $MEATZBENID= $result->ID;
                   echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$MEATZBENID' value='$MEATZBEN'><label class='Checkboxstyle'>$MEATZBEN";

}
?>
```

Comment: You're stacking the labels into another as childs. They should be siblings.

Comment: how should it be done? Thanks